# R-error: object cannot be coerced to type 'double' & non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm just trying to built a very easy Naive and SNaive forecasting model in RStudio, but somehow I keep bumping to an error when I'm trying to plot the accuracy metrics.

```
Amtrak.data = read_excel("Amtrak.xlsx")
Data.ts = ts(Amtrak.data$column1, start = c(1991,1), end = c(2004, 3), freq = 12)
nValid = 36
nTrain = length(Data.ts) - nValid
train.ts = window(Data.ts, start = c(1991,1), end = c(1991, nTrain))
valid.ts = window(Data.ts, start = c(1991, nTrain +1), end = c(1991, nTrain + nValid))
naive.pred = naive(train.ts, h = nValid)
snaive.pred = snaive(train.ts, h = nValid)
accuracy(naive.pred, valid.ts)
accuracy(snaive.pred, valid.ts)
```

Error that occurs:

> Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
>     (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In `!=.default`(actual, predicted) :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I already tried adjusting the values in matrices, like this:

```
naive.pred = as.matrix(naive.pred)
snaive.pred = as.matrix(snaive.pred)
valid.ts  = as.matrix(valid.ts)
```

But that only partly fixes the error:

> Error in actual != predicted : non-conformable arrays

I'm getting very frustrated, as this is supposed to be really easy.. Somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your data or example data that reproduces the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't really a chat forum. There are rules and expectations. Edited your extraneous comments at the end. Such expressions of furustration are considered "noisy" and of little use. We're frustrated as well. You are supposed to post enough code and data to reproduce the problem. Otherwise, there are a set of rules for closure and yours seems to fit one of them. Please read the intro material and use the [edit] facilities to improve your question. Nice personal image by the way.